# How to use compareTo for generics. (<E>, <Integer>...)

Tags: java, generics, iterator, compareto

I need to use compareTo() in program given by my profesor.
But that program includes generics. And there is problem with that function. So my question is how can i implement it.

```
if(node1.getElement().compareTo(node2.getElement()) < 0)
```

And i need some explanation for `java.util.Iterator;`
Because i need to use `iteration()` in the main class.
I am new to java. Be free to explain it to a newbie. Tnx guys

here is the wholeeeeeee code :D
https://pastebin.com/mA9igb1t

Comment: You need to share the class used, with only this we can do nothing

Comment: Number should extend Comparable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: in your `main` method you cannot use a generic `E`. You must use the correct type, `Integer` in your case.

There are two solutions for the comparator issue:

1. If you are sure `E` will always be a wrapper for a primitive type
   (like Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float or Double) you can declare
   SLL as
   `class SLL<E extends Number & Comparable> implements Iterable<E>`
   then your `if` will work.
   `SLL` doesn't have to implements `Comparable`.
2. Otherwise, you could use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in your `if`
   `BigDecimal node1Value = new BigDecimal(node1.getElement().toString());`
   `BigDecimal node2Value = new BigDecimal(node2.getElement().toString());`
   `if(node1Value.compareTo(node2Value) < 0)`

About iterator issue, since you have to call `.iterator()` on your `SLL` object, that class must implements [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).
You could read about iterators on [The Java Tutorials - The Collection Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html).
I also suggest to take a look at source code of [LinkedList](https://github.com/srisatish/openjdk/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java)